# How to associate a timer to my function..?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am facing another issue. I want to associate a timer to my function. 

Actually what i am doing is that i am tryin to store certain values in a database. A function is such that it calculates 5 values and stores them in a database. While storing them in the database it displays them in a textbox on the form. Now i want to display them one by one which it does. But it does it so fast that i can only see the last value that it enters in the database inside the textbox.


Can i make it show all the values slowly one by one.

`Private Sub dbInsert(ByVal strfile As String, ByVal hashoffile As String, ByVal p As Integer)
        'parameter to the above function (ByVal strfile As String)`

```
    DbConnection()
    cmd = "select * from hashtable"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "values")
    maxrows = ds.Tables("values").Rows.Count

    TextBox1.Text = p + 1
    TextBox2.Text = hashoffile
    TextBox3.Text = strfile
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim dsnewrow As DataRow
    dsnewrow = ds.Tables("values").NewRow()
    dsnewrow.Item("p_id") = TextBox1.Text
    dsnewrow.Item("process_name") = TextBox2.Text
    dsnewrow.Item("hash_value") = TextBox3.Text
    ds.Tables("values").Rows().Add(dsnewrow)
    da.Fill(ds)
    da.Update(ds, "values")
    'MsgBox("new Item added to database")
    con.Close()
    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your existing code.. It will help others to help you..:)

Comment: @Nalaka526 : Posted the code..

Comment: What are you actually trying to make it? Insert slowly? or insert at once and display slowly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Timer Control to your form
2. Move your code (retrieving data and displaying data) to Timer Controls `tick` event
3. Set Timer controls `Interval` Property as you required, to make it slow displaying values.
4. Call `TIMERCONTROLNAME.Enabled = True` to start timer.

Comment: can u explain a little bit more. actually i am not getting it